# dipstick channel is blocked

Tags: nissan

I found my dipstick is missing. Tried to insert another one but it's blocked after 6". The mechanic tried and failed. He needs to takeout the major parts to fix that. He said it's okay to drive like that? what could be the cause of the block? Nissan Sentra 2004

Comment: fine to drive except obviously you have no way to check the oil level. You may want to start changing your oil more frequently as a drain and fill is basically the only way to ensure you have the correct level.  Where did you have it changed last? Want to bet the guy at the quick lube broke it and didn't say anything..

Answer (score 3):

The remains of the old dipstick spring to mind. As mechanic says fine to drive.